# Add syntax highlighting for posts with the [polymer] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I propose that posts with [polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer) should be highlighted as though the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag were present. It seems like the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag is able to do a good job of highlighting html and javascript, even when the javascript isn't enclosed in `<script>` tags.

A few posts that would benefit from this:

- [Automatic node finding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530619/automatic-node-finding-not-working)
- [How does core-selector's 'core-select' event work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474020/how-does-core-selectors-core-select-event-work)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482194/bind-data-in-polymer-and-treat-it-as-html-not-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Done! All [polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer) posts now should up with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) mark-up. It's not the best, but it's definitely better than before.</s> Thanks for the suggestion!

Thanks to animuson pointing it out, new tags by default use no syntax highlighting. We changed [polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer) over to using syntax highlighting as predicted by prettify.js itself, and now [polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer) posts will highlight both HTML and Javascript found in them.

Comment: Is this really such a great idea? I mean, even the [tag:html] tag itself doesn't use HTML syntax highlighting, because it's so often used in conjunction with CSS. Shouldn't it just use default?

Comment: @animuson the default was not doing *any* styling, some styling is better than no styling, I think.

Comment: That's because by default tags have *none* as their highlighting, not *default*. His examples seem to get highlighted just fine using *default*, and for [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474020/how-does-core-selectors-core-select-event-work) the JavaScript will get highlighted too.

Comment: @animuson Ahhh, wasn't aware of that, just changed it to default, thanks!